# Does Apple provide notifications if device is hacked

Tags: malware, hacking

I recently used an app that was for live wallpapers and then got a pop up that made a beeping sound (like the typical bomb from movies).  I read some reviews of the app which describe the message as a scam, but for the future does apple even provide this type of message?

[Link to the google search of the app cover for the app I was using when the incident occured](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&biw=1396&bih=593&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=2GcSWszUGIS4jwO66YIg&q=live%20wallpaper%20by%20thermify&oq=live%20wallpaper%20by%20thermify&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4766.8663.0.8955.18.16.1.0.0.0.406.2119.0j5j4j0j1.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..8.5.795...0j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i67k1.0.Fsjgy7juWqQ#imgrc=RTkJKYz60dQQPM:)

[Link to img search of app cover of app I downloaded minutes before this one that may have also caused the incident (This one did lag which is a symptom listed for a virus, but also my device is sort of outdated and doesn't get updated any more so maybe the app is too updated](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9xQPkvWeKhx2sbYez1mjyHAFXjXKPYzTcW4EGvoLvGMc4m3_4gw)

[1st link used for research](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2017/04/08/how-to-tell-if-your-phone-or-tablet-has-virus.html&usg=AFQjCNEg6KrNc3TPygQfVlWUcLAWDslczQ)

[2nd site used for research](https://bigideatech.com/a-virus-on-your-iphone-or-a-tech-support-scam/)

Comment: The first and the second link are the same, is this how you wanted it to be?

Comment: No, I didn't mean to link the same link twice, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, any scary popup about viruses on any computer can safely be ignored. An actual message from an actual virus scanner (which doesn’t exist on iOS anyway) will be more measured.